# Custom UISegmentedControl Issue (Programmatically & Interface Builder)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I am creating a UISegmentedControl with custom images for each segment. Programmatically, this is working with me:

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 0, 170, 31)];
segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ebd-toolbar-bg"]];
[segmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"eatIcon"] atIndex:0 animated:NO];
[segmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buyIcon"] atIndex:1 animated:NO];
[segmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"doIcon"] atIndex:2 animated:NO];
segmentedControl.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
```

However, the segment's custom image does not fill the segment entirely and the background shows a little. The problem is that the background image does not have the same colour so it looks weird as shown below. You can see a little black around each segment.

[image: this]

I tried using `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` but that does not work either. Is there a way to set a segment's image size? If so, how? And to what size does it have to be?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `- (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets` method.
In your case that could be:

```
[segmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"eatIcon"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,10,0,10)] atIndex:0 animated:NO];
```

Please note that you need to determine the correct values for the `UIEdgeInsetsMake(CGFloat top, CGFloat left, CGFloat bottom, CGFloat right);` function